# Solving two equations for $p$ and $q$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

How we obtain  from the equations $z^2-pqxy=0$ and $z-a(xp+yq)=0$ that $p=\frac{z}{cx}$ and $q=\frac{cz}{y}$, where $a(c+\frac{1}{c})=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first equation then the second,
$$a(xp)^2-z(xp)+a(xp)(yq)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad a(xp)^2-z(xp)+az^2=0\ .$$
You can easily show that $yq$ satisfies the same quadratic, so
$$xp,yq=z\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4a^2}}{2a}\right)\ .$$
Therefore
$$p=\frac{z}{cx}\quad\hbox{where}\quad c=\frac{2a}{1\pm\sqrt{1-4a^2}}\ .$$
Unless you have more information, it is impossible to tell which sign you should take.  Whichever it is, you get
$$q=\frac{z}{cy}$$
with the other sign in $c$.  In both cases it is easy to show that
$$c+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{a}\ .$$

Comment: @ david...thanks